# BIDS DTS_E_PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, ssis, bids

Group,
I have Visual Studio (VS) 2005 and 2008 installed on my local machine.  I am creating SSIS packages using BI Studio and the package will build and run fine on my local machine. However, as soon as I move it to the server I get the error: Error SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW. The product level insufficient for component...

It is basically a simple SQL query that dumps data to an Excel file (even a dump to a .csv will not work).

I narrowed it down to be an integration issue when using VS 2008 because if my co-worker re-creates the package, moves it to the server and runs the package he doesn't get an error. He only has VS 2005 installed.

Is anyone else out there having the same issue, and if yes do you know of any work arounds?  I am not seeing any clear cut solutions out on Google.  Otherwise I am just going to uninstall VS 2008. Talk about a headache...

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely the issue is related to VS 2008. Probably you don't have full SSIS installed.

See details at 
http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2006/11/11/ssis-product-level-is-insufficient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I´m having this same trouble. What I noticed is that the server has the SSIS service up and running, but remotely, I open the Management Console and connect to my remote server and the SSIS service does not appear. I tried  with other machine and it appears the service. I think I have a security problem.

I suggest to do the same.

Regards,